# Google Analytics custom report that shows more users than sessions

Tags: google-analytics, users, session

Can anyone give me an example where the users count will be greater than the number of sessions?

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en

As per Google’s explanation I am pasting some contents from the site which Google gave as example

Here is an example of two sessions from two different users:

Session 1:

User enters to Page A User navigates to Page B User navigates back to Page A End of session Session 2:

User enters to Page C User navigates to Page B End of session Summary

Page A: 2 Pageviews, 1 Session, 1 Unique Pageview, 1 User, 1 Entrance Page B: 2 Pageviews, 0 Sessions, 2 Unique Pageviews, 2 Users, 0 Entrances Page C: 1 Pageview, 1 Session, 1 Unique Pageview, 1 User, 1 Entrance Totals: 5 Pageviews, 2 Sessions, 4 Unique Pageviews, 2 Users, 2 Entrances

In the above scenario the total user count is 2 which is equal to session count. What I am looking for is a scenario wherein the users count will be greater than the sessions.

Answer (score 1):

In https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956047?hl=en&ref_topic=1012046 are well explained two scenarios where users are more than sessions count in a Google Analytics custom report:

> ### **SCENARIO 1**
>
> **Session 1:**
>
> User enters to Page A
>
> User navigates to Page B
>
> User navigates back to Page A
>
> End of session
>
> **Session 2:**
>
> User enters to Page C
>
> User navigates to Page B
>
> End of session
>
> ***Summary***
>
> ---
>
> **Page A:** 2 Pageviews, 1 Session, 1 Unique Pageview, 1 User, 1 Entrance
>
> **Page B:** 2 Pageviews, 0 Sessions, 2 Unique Pageviews, 2 Users, 0 Entrances
>
> **Page C:** 1 Pageview, 1 Session, 1 Unique Pageview, 1 User, 1 Entrance
>
> **Totals:** 5 Pageviews, 2 Sessions, 4 Unique Pageviews, 2 Users, 2 Entrances
>
> **In Session 1, Page A gets a session, while Page B does not, because it
>   was not the first hit of the session. Likewise, in Session 2, only
>   Page C gets a session**.
>
> ---
>
> ### **SCENARIO 2**
>
> When using the Hour dimension A custom report that
>   combines Hour or Hour of Day with Sessions and Users may show more
>   users than sessions for any given hour.
>
> If a session spans multiple hours, the session will only be counted
>   for the first hour, but the user will be counted for every hour the
>   session is active. For example, if a session begins at 8:50 and ends
>   at 9:10, there will be a user attributed to 8 and 9 o'clock, one
>   session at 8 o'clock, but zero sessions at 9 o'clock.
>
> **Therefore, 9 o'clock will have one user but zero sessions**.

Answer (score 0):

I read about changing IP during session may create 2 different users during one session. This can happen with dynamic ip providers.

I guess there is no other way. Pages always get session, not depending on first hit on not.